# passing zend-framework variable from controller to view

Tags: zend-framework, controller

I try to copy and localize a zendframework project
seems every thing worked good but in final output in browser no variable from controller passed
and this html code without CSS and JS loading are shown

```
<div id="content-slides">

                <?= $this->layout()->content; ?>

            </div>

        </div>
----------------------------------------------------------------

                    <ul class="list-col">
<li>
    <a href="<?=$this->url(array('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'productscomputer', 'action' => 'list'), 'shop')?>"><?=$this->_("Products")?></a>
```

this was index.phtml that remain un parsed
but seems layout is pares and

```
'<?=$this->baseUrl()?>'
```

parsed to my baseURL (in rendered final html outout)
nothing had change from original project but every configuration edited
projects use 2 module and no controller are in application path

Comment: check your apache config for: AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml

Comment: thanks 
i think it's not my solution. I try this and not works

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Which variable do yo want to see in a view?

Comment: All variable passing through controller to view such "baseurl"  & sitemap items

Comment: How do you pass the variables to the view? via $this->assign(), $this->view->... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure [short open tags are turned on](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) in your new environment.

Comment: but if short open tags are turned off, how come `<?=$this->baseUrl?>` works?